# Hide google markers with specific id + google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having array of markers with four different types of icon, i want to hide specific markers with the external check box event. Here is my code:

```
prevMarkers = [];
for(j=0;j<count;j++){
  if(taxiData[j].is_active == 1){
    if(taxiData[j].is_busy == 0){
      taxiIcon = 'available.png';
      taxiId = 'available';
    }else if(taxiData[j].is_busy == 1){
      taxiIcon = 'onway.png';
      taxiId = 'onway';
    }else if(taxiData[j].is_busy == 2){
      taxiIcon = 'waiting.png';
      taxiId = 'waiting';
    }
  }else{
    taxiIcon = 'inactive.png';
    taxiId = 'inactive';
  }
  tempdata = [taxiData[j].driver_id,parseFloat(taxiData[j].latitude),parseFloat(taxiData[j].longitude),taxiIcon,taxiId];
  taxiMarkers.push(tempdata);
}
console.log(taxiMarkers);
marker.setMap(null);
for( i = 0; i < taxiMarkers.length; i++ ) {
  var position = new google.maps.LatLng(taxiMarkers[i][1], taxiMarkers[i][2]);
  iconBase = "<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>" + '/images/'+(taxiMarkers[i][3]);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
    icon:  iconBase,
    id:taxiMarkers[i][4],
    // title: markers[i][0],
    optimized:false,
  });
  prevMarkers.push(marker);
```

As shown i have four ids, and i want to disable using checkbox.Please provide appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add checkbox with general class `checkbox` and the value of everyone of them represent the `id` of icon type :

```
<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='my-checkbox' value='1'/>Type 1
<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='my-checkbox' value='2'/>Type 2
<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='my-checkbox' value='3'/>Type 3
<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='my-checkbox' value='4'/>Type 4
```

Then attach `change` event to them using class `.checkbox` :

```
$('body').on('change', '.checkbox', function(){
    //show or hide markers when checkbox status changed
})
```

Inside the event add condition to check if the `checkbox` changed is checked or not and based to this you will show or hide the related markers :

```
if($(this).is(':checked')){
     //show the related markers 
}else{
     //Hide the related markers
}
```

To get the related markers with every `checkbox` you could use the `value` :

```
var marker_id= $(this).val();

for( i = 0; i < prevMarkers.length; i++ ) {
    var marker = prevMarkers[i];      
    if(marker==marker_id){
         //Show marker or hide it using .setMap(map); or .setMap(null);
    }
}
```

**Full JS code :**

```
$('body').on('change', '.checkbox', function(){
    var map_or_null=null;

    if($(this).is(':checked')){
         map_or_null = map;
    }

    var marker_id= $(this).val();

    for( i = 0; i < prevMarkers.length; i++ ) {
        var marker = prevMarkers[i];  

        if(marker==marker_id){
             marker.setMap(map_or_null);
        }
    }
})
```

Hope this helps.